# Firebase Firestore and Cloud Functions are showing wrong reads, writes and deletes numbers?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have firestore structure like this:

```
users(collection):
    -userID_1(document):
        email: email1@gmail.com
        name: userName_1
        photo: photoUrl
        uid: userID_1
        followersNum: 1
        followingNum: 0
        questionsNum: 0
    -userID_2(document):
        email: email2@gmail.com
        name: userName_2
        photo: photoUrl
        uid: userID_2
        followersNum: 0
        followingNum: 1
        questionsNum: 0
followingFollowersPoints(collection):
    -userID_2(document):
        -following(collection):
            -userID_1(document)
                -points: 1
```

My Firestore and Cloud Functions numbers before I did anything:
[image]
[image]
There are 0 clud functions invocations and 0 reads,writes,deletes for today(Feb.17)
Then I deployed my cloud function with firebase deploy --only functions:followUser, then I open firestore usage and get this numbers:
[image]
I didn't open my app and I haven't touched firestore console, I just reopened Usage page in firestore, How is this possible?
Then I manually update two user documents and delete one documents in following collection before testing cloud function, so I update one field in two documents and delete one document but I get this numbers:
This is how firestore has changed:

```
As you can see I only updated two field, from value 1 to value 0 and deleted one document in following colelction
users(collection):
    -userID_1(document):
        email: email1@gmail.com
        name: userName_1
        photo: photoUrl
        uid: userID_1
        followersNum: 0
        followingNum: 0
        questionsNum: 0
    -userID_2(document):
        email: email2@gmail.com
        name: userName_2
        photo: photoUrl
        uid: userID_2
        followersNum: 0
        followingNum: 0
        questionsNum: 0
followingFollowersPoints(collection):
    -userID_2(document):
        -following(collection):
```

And this is firestore usage:
 [image]

Then I manually add same document in following collection which will invoke cloud function and my cloud function updates one field in two documents. This is my firestore structure after I added that document:

```
users(collection):
        -userID_1(document):
            email: email1@gmail.com
            name: userName_1
            photo: photoUrl
            uid: userID_1
            **followersNum: 1 -CloudFunction updated this field**
            followingNum: 0
            questionsNum: 0
        -userID_2(document):
            email: email2@gmail.com
            name: userName_2
            photo: photoUrl
            uid: userID_2
            followersNum: 0
            **followingNum: 1 -CloudFunction updated this field**
            questionsNum: 0
    followingFollowersPoints(collection):
        -userID_2(document):
            -following(collection):
                **-userID_1(document) - I added this document that invokes fucntion**
                    -points: 1
```

And these are usage numbers after cloud functions was invoked:
[image]
[image]
Then just to make sure numbers are updated, I refreshed browser and get this numbers:
[image]
As I am writing this for about 15 min, number of reads whent up to 177 !?!?

### I haven't touched firestore or app, while I am writing this on stackoverflow numbers are going up for no reason.

This is my CloudFunction code:

```
admin.initializeApp();
 const db = admin.firestore();

 export const followUser = functions.firestore
    .document('followingFollowersPoints/{myUserId}/following/{followingUserId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const myUserId = context.params.myUserId               //update my following count
        const followingUserId = context.params.followingUserId //update his followers count
        const myUserDocRef = db.collection('users').doc(myUserId)
        const followingUserDocRef = db.collection('users').doc(followingUserId)
        return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
            return transaction.getAll(myUserDocRef, followingUserDocRef) //**********THESE ARE TWO READS*****************
                    .then(docs => {

                        const myUserData = docs[0].data()
                        const followingUserData = docs[1].data()

                        if(myUserData != null && followingUserData != null){
                            //since I am following someone - increase my followingNum
                            const newFollowingCount = myUserData.followingNum + 1
                            //then increse his followersNum
                            const newFollowersCount = followingUserData.followersNum + 1

                            //update my followingNum field in user document
                            //*******THIS IS ONE WRITE*********
                            transaction.update(myUserDocRef, {
                                followingNum : newFollowingCount
                            });
                            //*******THIS IS ONE WRITE*********
                            //update friends followersNum
                            transaction.update(followingUserDocRef, {
                                followersNum : newFollowersCount
                            });
                        }
                    });
          }).then(() => console.log('Transaction succeeded'))  
    });
```

I really don't know how I get this numbers, It just doesn't make any sense. I don;t have any other cloud function that can be invoked with this changes from first cloud function. 177 reads is just too much when I only had two reads in cloud function.

Comment: If you have questions about billing, you should contact Firebase support directly.  But you should know that viewing documents in the console counts as reads too.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand how billing works but I don't understand how I got that many reads. Is my Cloud Function bad or something else? I know that viewing documents counts as reads but I only have 2 documents in 'users' collection and one document in 'followingFollowersPoints' and one in 'following' collection that function add. That is 4 documents. So there is no chance that between me taking screenshot of usage and deploying function I opened those 4 documents 38 times or that while writing this question to stackoverflow and then refreshing usage page I opened 27 documents.

Comment: I'm saying that you should reach out to supply to also understand how you are being billed for reads, and how to understand what the console is reading out to you, if it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it few more times and then contact Firebase support.